# System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated="..." is not valid. 'TargetUpdated' must be a RoutedEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add event handler to a cell in DataTable by editing the cell style. Specifically, I'm setting

```
<EventSetter Event="TargetUpdated" Handler="TaskDescription_TextChanged1Event"/>
```

And here's the error that I'm getting:

```
System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated="TaskDescription_TextChanged1Event" 
   is not valid. 'TargetUpdated' must be a RoutedEvent registered with a name that 
   ends with the keyword "Event".
```

Here's the code for TaskDescription_TextChanged1Event:

```
    public void TaskDescription_TextChanged1Event(object sender, 
                              RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

What should I do for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `EventSetters` for events which are not routed, however according to the documentation [`FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.targetupdated.aspx) is an alias event for [`Binding.TargetUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated.aspx), which is routed, so subscribing to that might work out.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But TaskDescription_TextChanged1Event is never called if I set it this way

Comment: @ArsenZahray: Did you set [`NotifyOnTargetUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated.aspx) for the binding? Also why don't you use [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged.aspx) or something?

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't figure out how to use TextChanged with ContentPresenter