# How to add raise event in style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can't find how to add in a button style the raise event to click button when there is a touchdown (with touch screen), do you know how to add this in the style?
*I need to do it because when using touch screen the clickEvent is not fire at first time, generally at second touch (when focus is set to window).*

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TouchDown">
```

How to add the Raise click event??

```
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to **invoke** (cause) it or add a **handler** to an existing event? If you want to cause it - you can't. If you want to add a handler, then this question is a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460201/how-to-set-an-event-function-via-a-style.

Comment: That makes little sense. When tapping a button you already get a Click event. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: If you want to do something in a style that will cause Event A to raise Event B, write an attached property that adds an Event A handler, and make the handler raise Event B. Not hard to do, just search SO/Google for a good minimal WPF attached property example. But maybe Joey's got a point; what are you really trying to accomplish, conceptually?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the touch event is fire each time with a touch screen, but not the click event. Actually we have a lot of controls using the click events, to be sure it fire when we use a touch event i wanted to fire the click event when th touch down is fire (as touch down is done before click).